# Javascript not executing when using link_to

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails

I have couple javascript functions that attaching action to buttons in controller view `some/index`. I navigate to `some/index` using `link_to` method. But when i'm using `link_to` method, buttons has no attached javascript actions (in `some/index` view). When i try open `some/index` directly from my browser, buttons have all attached actions i need and working fine.

**some.js.coffee**

```
jQuery ->
    $('.my-btn').on 'click', (event) ->
    ...
```

I think it can't attach actions to buttons in `some/index` when i'm using link_to because it already executed all javascript in `root/index` view and  page is not refreshing when i'm using `link_to`.
How can i solve this problem? Still want to use `link_to`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a result of Turbolinks. You can get around this with the following:

```
$(document).on 'click', '.my-btn', (event) ->
  ...
```

This is happening because *Turbolinks* is loading the page, and there isn't a document ready event being fired. You want to wait until Turbolinks fires the `page:load` event.

*You do not need the `jQuery ->` with the above code.*